# Retrieve AJAX Post Data on Classic ASP Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp-classic, request.form

What i'm doing is depending on a link clicked, re-building the URL and reading in variables from the URL to then do an AJAX post call to a classic ASP page and subsequently insert the post values into an SQL database.

this is in the document.ready() function so that when the URL gets changed it will read in the new values;

```
        //check if there's a video to log, and log that video
    var params = {};
    params["loggedFrom"] = getUrlVars()["loggedFrom"];
    params["logVideo"] = getUrlVars()["logVideo"];
    params["ipAddress"] = getUrlVars()["IPAddress"];
    params["fromApp"] = "P360";
    params["fromPage"] = "P360 Trading Overview";
    params["videoName"] = getUrlVars()["videoName"];
    //alert(params["loggedFrom"]);
    if(params["logVideo"]   == "true"){
        var now = new Date();
        now = now.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"p360TradingLog.asp",
            data: params,
            success : function(d){
                alert("this post was successful");              
            }
        });
    }
```

params[] seems to be containing the data correctly as when doing the

```
alert(params["logVideo"]);
```

it returns the correct values, but i don't receive the "This post was successful" alert.  My question is what should my code be in the p360TradingLog.asp page in order to get these posted values and insert them correctly? This is my current code but is not working correctly.

```vb
<%
        Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
        set ipAddress = Request.Form("params")("ipAddress");
        set videoName = Request.Form("params")("videoName");
        set fromPage = Request.Form("params")("fromPage");
        set fromApp = Request.Form("params")("fromApp");
        set loggedFrom = Request.Form("params")("loggedFrom");
        set timeOfDay = Now;
        var conStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Data Source=xxxxx";
        con.Open(conStr);
        Set rs = con.Execute("Insert into dbo.tbl_Prospect_Video_Tracking(IPAddress,videoName,fromPage,fromApp,loggedFrom,dtViewed)values('" + ipAddress + "','" + videoName + "','" + fromPage + "','" + fromApp + "','" + loggedFrom + "','" + timeOfDay + "')");
        //alert(insertSQL); 
        rs.close();         
        con.close();
%>
```

Is there a way for me to test on the P360TradingLog.asp page what might be erroring out?  i'm not familiar with these posts so sorry if these seem very lamen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <%
    dim con, ipaddress, videoname, frompage, fromapp, loggedfrom, timeofday, constr, sqlstr

    Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ipAddress = Request.Form("ipAddress")
    videoName = Request.Form("videoName")
    fromPage = Request.Form("fromPage")
    fromApp = Request.Form("fromApp")
    loggedFrom = Request.Form("loggedFrom")
    timeOfDay = Now

    conStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=clink;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Data Source=xxxxx"
    con.Open conStr
    sqlstr = "Insert into dbo.tbl_Prospect_Video_Tracking(IPAddress,videoName,fromPage,fromApp,loggedFrom,dtViewed)values('" & ipAddress & "','" & videoName & "','" & fromPage & "','" & fromApp & "','" & loggedFrom & "','" & timeOfDay & "')"
    con.Execute(sqlstr)


    con.close
    %>
```

First of all you appear to be using Javascript as your server side scripting language, which is perfectly valid, however I've changed it to VBScript here because I'm a lot more familiar with the syntax.

You're using "set" do declare string variables, which looks wrong.  When you use request.form you only use the name of the form field, and you don't need to use a recordset as in this context you aren't retrieving data with a select query

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i've gone through and made the recommended changes to my code, but still don't seem to be getting a success message.  is there anything i can put into the above code to test that page is receiving the form variables correctly?

Comment: You can always use `Response.Write Request.Form("ipAddress")` (or any other form field name) to get the page to display the data it's recieved

Comment: NB - I suggest you change database usernames and passwords before you post connection strings on a public forum

Comment: they are changed, i figured if i left them as blank people would comment how the connection doesn't have user credentials, but thanks for looking out, i'll mask the fake ones so people know they're fake

Comment: It appears all of the post data is getting seen correctly on the page, what i am receiving is a :Category:Microsoft VBScript runtime 
Description:Type mismatch: ['string:"Insert into dbo.tbl_"]' Does having a underscore "_" in a string cause this error? i know that an underscore can separate multiple lines in classic asp, but i figured within double quotes for a string it would be alright?

Comment: Type mismatch errors usually occur when the page is expecting a number and gets a string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50053/discussion-between-john-and-nick-g)